# Displaying current datetime value in xsl

Tags: datetime, xslt

We are trying to display the current datetime value in XSL report along with the meridian and the timezone. I am able to achieve the same using the below tag except for the meridian. Please advice.

```
date:format-date(date:date-time(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z')
```

Tried below, but the tt is for Microsoft date format and it is coming the same in the report and I m not able to get the expected AM or PM

```
date:format-date(date:date-time(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt Z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are obviously **not** using XSLT 2.0, but some sort of an extension to XSLT 1.0 (perhaps EXSLT?), try:

```
date:format-date(date:date-time(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, try

```
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ssP Z
```

Full doc [can be found here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like EXSLT to me as well, in which case Michael is correct with the suggestion to use "a" to get AM/PM.  If your declaration of the "date" namespace is:

```
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
```

then that's what you're using.  Implementations of EXSLT dates-and-times are supposed to support the Java JDK 1.1 SimpleDateFormat, so you can use [this page](http://rtfm.vtt.net/java/javanut/ch29_18.htm) as a reference. You will probably also want to refer to the [exslt.org](http://exslt.org/) page.